# Jquery clear my textfields after submit

Tags: php, jquery

I wrote some `jquery` code to send my data to a `php` file that puts the data into my `database` without reloading the page(that works), but after that I want to clear the input fields, there seems to be a problem, but I can't find it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrapper').find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        submitGegevens();
    });
});
function submitGegevens(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "addComment.php",
      data: {
        'name' : $('input[name="name"]').val(),
        'email' : $('input[name="email"]').val(),
        'phone' : $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
        'comment' : $('textarea[name="comment"]').val(),
      }
    }).done(function(data){
        $('.error').html(data);
    });
    if ($(data).is(":empty")){
        $('input[name="name"]').val(''),
        $('input[name="email"]').val(''),
        $('input[name="phone"]').val(''),
        $('textarea[name="comment"]').val(''),
    };
}
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php
include "functies.php";
//PREG_MATCH:
function controleerEmail($email){
    return(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}
$message = '';
    if(empty($_POST['email']) or !controleerEmail($_POST['email'])){
    $message .= 'Please enter a valid email address.<br>';
}
echo $message;

if(empty($message)){
    klantToevoegen($_POST['name'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['comment']);
}

?>
```

Comment: I added the php code. So what needs to happen; the jqeury should check for a valid email adres and the input field email may not be empty. when this is ok, the data should be sent to the database and the input fields of the form should be cleared without page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` is available only in the done callback, so you need to test whether it is empty in the callback itself

```
function submitGegevens() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addComment.php",
        data: {
            'name': $('input[name="name"]').val(),
                'email': $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                'phone': $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
                'comment': $('textarea[name="comment"]').val(),
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('.error').html(data);
        if ($(data.trim()).is(":empty")) {
            $('input[name="name"]').val(''),
            $('input[name="email"]').val(''),
            $('input[name="phone"]').val(''),
            $('textarea[name="comment"]').val(''),
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: I added the php code.
So what needs to happen;
the jqeury should check for a valid email adres and the input field email may not be empty. when this is ok, the data should be sent to the database and the input fields of the form should be cleared without page refresh.